# Hide carrier title on checkout page. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

I need to hide carrier title on checkout page only when price is 0.00.

[image]

Or even the js file from where this carrier title is displayed will be really helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by following Steps below:

> Step 1: Create new template for shipping method item
>   In your custom module directory, create a new file:
>    `<your_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/custom-method-item-template.html.`
>   In this file, add the following code.
>
> It is copied from the `<Magento_Checkout_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html` template, comment **`<td>`** for method title.

```
<tr class="row"
    click="element.selectShippingMethod">
    <td class="col col-method">
        <input type="radio"
               class="radio"
               ifnot="method.error_message"
               ko-checked="element.isSelected"
               ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
               attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                   'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
    </td>
    <td class="col col-price">
        <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
    </td>
    <!--<td class="col col-method"
        attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.method_title" /> -->
    <td class="col col-carrier"
        attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.carrier_title" />
</tr>
<tr class="row row-error"
    if="method.error_message">
    <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
        <div role="alert" class="message error">
            <div text="method.error_message"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="no-display">
           <input type="radio"
                  attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
       </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> Step 2: Create a new template for shipping methods list
>   In your custom module directory, create a new file:
>    `<your_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/custom-method-list-template.html.`
>   In this file, add the following code. It uses the code from the `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html` template, comment line for Method Title:

```
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
    <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
        <thead>
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="col col-method" translate="'Select Method'"></th>
            <th class="col col-price" translate="'Price'"></th>
            <!--<th class="col col-method" translate="'Method Title'"></th> -->
            <th class="col col-carrier" translate="'Carrier Title'"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'} -->
        <!--ko template: { name: element.shippingMethodItemTemplate} --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

> Step 3: Override shipping step configuration
>   In your custom module directory, create a new file:   `<your_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml.`
>   In this file, add the following code.
>
> It overrides the `shippingMethodListTemplate` and `shippingMethodItemTemplate` properties of `<Magento_Checkout_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingMethodItemTemplate" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/custom-method-item-template</item>
                                                        <item name="shippingMethodListTemplate" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/custom-method-list-template</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Source:  [Customize the list of shipping methods](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_shipping_methods.html)

Comment: This is perfect but can i do only if the price is 0.00. In short when price is 0.00 then hide this carrier title

Comment: Or even if you can guide me the js from where this carrier title value is displayed

Comment: yeah, you can check `<Magento_Checkout_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js` and `<Magento_Checkout_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information.js`

Comment: I have tried commenting from both this js file it is not helping. Can you just chk once & guide me on that?

Comment: don't really know how to tweak it as the estimation for the formatted price is a different method. I think you can make your own custom js/jquery method to implement your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **Method Name** from the admin configuration like this.

[image]

**And you can see the result now on the front page. The title is removed.**

[image]

Comment: I need to hide only on checkout page + only when price is 0.00